# Error: filter:notarray when using filters with Lodash Groupby

Tags: angularjs

This is how I am getting listing.

```
    $scope.events = [];
    $scope.groupevent = [];

    Event.getList().then(function(data){
        $scope.events = data.events;
        $rootScope.events = data.events;

        angular.forEach($scope.events,function(value,key){
            value.groupdate = value.startDate.substring(0,7)+'-01';
            console.log(value.groupdate);
        });

        $scope.events = _.orderBy($scope.events, ['startDate'], ['asc']);
        $scope.groupevent = _.groupBy($scope.events,'groupdate');
        console.log($scope.groupevent);
    });
```

I have another function which I want to use for filter: it looks like below.

```
$scope.greaterThan = function(){
    var prop='endDate';
    var val=Date.now();
    return function(item){
        return new Date(item[prop]) > val;
    }
};
```

But when I am `ng-repeat`:

```
ng-repeat="(key,x) in groupevent | filter:greaterThan()"
```

it says: `Error: filter:notarray`